# installed shiny and shinydashboard with sudo and now, some of applications does not load

Tags: r, shiny, ubuntu-16.04, shinydashboard

I am on a server with ubuntu 16.04, R version 3.2.3. I have several shiny applications hosted. I updated shiny package and shiny dashboard package in R with sudo. Now, some of the applications work properly (as before) but some of them load with an error and this is the log:

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:43323 Error in loadNamespace(i,
>   c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :    there is no
>   package called ‘promises’ Warning: Error in : package or namespace
>   load failed for ‘shinydashboard’ Stack trace (innermost first):
>       41: library
>        1: runApp Error: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
>
> Execution halted

I have updated the "promises" package with sudo, but nothing has changed. here is the sessionInfo():

> sessionInfo() R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) Platform:
>   x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C  [3]
>   LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8  [5]
>   LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8  [7]
>   LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C
>   LC_TELEPHONE=C [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base

Even if I select one the working apps and copy the whole directory into a new one, the new copied application does not come up!
there is no problem with applications, but I do not know what is the problem!
please help

Comment: check these links : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-16-04 , https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/problems-installing-shiny , https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2073

Comment: the problem is that my applications were working properly. nothing was wrong , but I did a mistake and tried to update the shiny package in sudo, and after that I updated shinydashboard Rcpp and promisis. Now, some of the applications work, and some of them are not working! I don't know why is that.

Comment: it may be due to the pacakge missmatch or package updates for few of them, try with R updated version

Comment: You might need to update the packages as the shiny user which is the default user for shiny apps. Check .libPaths() as sudo and shiny to see where they're pointing. It could be that the shiny user isn't using the sudo location.